# Scrape information about iXBRL link inside source code with python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

First of all, here is page i want to scrape : https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/09382107/filing-history

I have a python script that currently gets me all the iXBRL files and save them inside my folder. I would like to get the informations about those files : "Date" and "Description" as string, my problem is that i only want to get the "Date" and "Description" of the file with iXBRL link.

This is what I have so far:

```
link_filling_historic = "https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/09382107/filing-history"
r = requests.get(link_filling_historic)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

info = soup.find('table', {'class': 'full-width-table'})
info = soup.findChildren(['tr'])
info_of_iXBRL_files = []
other_info = []


for item in info:
  if "xhtml" in item:
     info_of_iXBRL_files.append(item)
  else :
     other_info.append(item)

print(info_of_iXBRL_files)
```

output :

```
[]
```

My idea was to keep the item from my list with "xhtml" inside it and remove the other to be able then to extract easely the text from each item.
The output is an empty list meaning that he doesn't recognize any "xhtml" string in the item of my list. I don't get why

Any suggestions on how I might get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/09382107/filing-history'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
table_div = soup.find('table',class_='full-width-table')
rows = table_div.find_all('tr')
table = {}
row_index = 1
for tr in rows:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    ls = []
    td_index = 0
    for td in tds:
        text = td.get_text().strip()
        if td_index != 1 and td_index != 3:
            ls.append(text)
        if td_index == 3:
            #a = td.find_all('a',string="Download iXBRL",href=True)
            #if len(a) > 0:
                #for tag in a:
                    #href = tag['href']
            a = td.select_one('a',string="Download iXBRL",href=True)
            if a:
                href = a['href']
                ls.append(href)
                table[row_index] = ls
                row_index += 1
        td_index += 1    
print(table)
```

Output

```
{1: ['04 Mar 2021',
  'Micro company accounts made up to 31 December 2019',
  '/company/09382107/filing-history/MzI5MzM0OTU0OGFkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1'],
 2: ['04 Mar 2021',
  'Micro company accounts made up to 31 December 2018',
  '/company/09382107/filing-history/MzI5MzMzNTIwM2FkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1'],
 3: ['09 Nov 2018',
  'Accounts for a dormant company made up to 31 December 2017',
  '/company/09382107/filing-history/MzIxOTA5MTA2N2FkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1'],
 4: ['06 Dec 2017',
  'Accounts for a dormant company made up to 31 January 2017',
  '/company/09382107/filing-history/MzE5MjEyNzU2M2FkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1'],
 5: ['04 Nov 2016',
  'Accounts for a dormant company made up to 31 January 2016',
  '/company/09382107/filing-history/MzE2MTE5NTk3NWFkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1']}
```

In this table there is an td without required in your output with index 1